# Can't make a centered rect with svg.js

Tags: svg, svg.js

I would like to have a rect centered on my body.
This works for a circle :

```
draw.circle('200','50').fill('#f00').attr({ cx: '50%', cy: '50%' })
```

This not works :

```
draw.rect('200','50').fill('#f00').attr({ cx: '50%', cy: '50%' })
draw.rect('200','50').fill('#f00').move('50%','50%')
```

How to do this (without `$(window).width()/2`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply: You cant. To avoid clutter in the library the calls to `move()` only set the attribute on the element and dont do other magic. Since rectangles have no cx and cy you cant do it with the library alone.